# small div fader with interval & play/pause function

Tags: jquery, fadein, setinterval, fadeout, css-selectors

i am playing around with a small fader.
it works fine with a single child element, but with elements in elements not:
http://jsfiddle.net/cz9a2/

should be:

```
<div class="fadein">
<div class="fadd"><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg"></div>
<div class="fadd"><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg"></div>
<div class="fadd"><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

result: ( checked with firebug )

```
<div class="fadein">
<div class="fadd" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="fadd" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="fadd" style="opacity: 0.00000555164;"></div>
<img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="opacity: 0.00000555164;">
<img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg" style="opacity: 0.000298526;">
<img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg" style="opacity: 0.000298526;">
</div>
```

it seems,  :first-child is not the right method to fade a div ( fadd ) after another div ( fadd )...

Comment: Can you specify please exactly what it is you actually expect to happen? When clicking on the first visible image, do you simply want to fade in the others 1-by-1 or show next, hide current or....?

Comment: there is my first solution, just with img and no parent elements. now i would like to get it work with parent elements like the divs with the class "fadd"

Comment: i would like to fade to the next, and after the last element automatically to the first again. kind of loop, until i pause it or play it again

Answer (score 0):

I reworked the functions a bit to make all of the code execute on the interval, so it fades in and out the right items.

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/cz9a2/48/

```
 var pauseplay;

function startFader() {

    //Fade out the first visible item
    $x = $(".fadd:visible").fadeOut(1000);

    // Get the next sibling
    $next = $x.next();

    // if the next is not an element, go back to the first one
    if ($next.length == 0) $next = $(".fadd:first-child");

    // Fade the next one in
    $next.fadeIn(1000);
}

function stopFader() {
    window.clearInterval(pauseplay);
    console.log("stop");
}

$('.fadein .fadd:gt(0)').hide();

pauseplay = window.setInterval(startFader, 2000);


var $button = $('#toggler');
$button.toggle(function() {
    stopFader();
    $(this).toggleClass('playin pausin');
}, function() {

    $(this).toggleClass('pausin playin');

    pauseplay = window.setInterval(startFader, 2000);

});​
```